# how to import and use spark-dynamodb in my pyspark code

Tags: pyspark, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to write data from a json file to dynamodb. came across [spark-dynamodb](https://github.com/audienceproject/spark-dynamodb)

how do i import this package in the pyspark script?

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked ([GitHub spark-dynamodb](https://github.com/audienceproject/spark-dynamodb)) to reads:

> Note: When running from pyspark shell, you can add the library as:
>
> `pyspark --packages com.audienceproject:spark-dynamodb_<spark-scala-version>:<version>`

Does that answer your question?